# Windows 10 - How to create users that can login in any computer of the network

Tags: windows-10, local-area-network

I am trying to create a small computer lab for my company office. We have about 5 computers all running Windows 10 pro (one runs Windows 10 home).

I want to be able to create users for each of the employees of the company so they can login in any of the computers of the office (all of them are connected with a lan connection), but I am struggling to find any information online about how to do it.

One of the computers acts as the "server" (meaning it is where we store all data). The reason why I want this setup is so I can display or hide the shared folders from the server computer depending on the user logged in. I also want to use SVN across the computers with the server owning the repositories.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: you use a domain and install active directory. This is EXACTLY the use case of active directory.

Btw., why the heck do you even bother with SVN - there is hardly a case where it makes sense these days, ever since GIT took over and provides more.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer TomTom. I did a bit of research and it seems I cannot create a domain with Windows 10 (only with Windows Server).

Comment: Yes, but then a lab in a pro setup has access for server licenses. This is not a place for homework, this place here is for pros. I need a server for a alb, my visual studio license covers everything.